# Proper way to indirectly reference a function in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I've found that I can use Get-Content function:NAME to get ScriptBlock, and use that as function reference.

```
function plusOne {
  param([int] $p)      
  $p + 1
}

plusOne 100    #--> 101

$intOp = (Get-Content function:plusOne)

&$intOp 100    # --> 101
```

I just wonder if this is the proper way to do this ? Is there any other option ?

Comment: I would do: `(Get-Item function:plusOne).ScriptBlock` or just `$function:plusOne`. Anyways, what is the background? Why would you do this or need this for? You can also directly reference the function itself: `&intOp 100` or create a ScriptBlock: `$intOp = { param([int] $p) $p + 1 }`

Comment: @zett42 I think that's pretty the same question as mine.

Comment: @iRon Just $function:plusOne. This is perfect. Thanks